# How auto format text when copy + paste in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i wonder how i can format text when user paste to input in react.

What i need:

eg: i have this codes

10202 20192 29192

i want when paste to input auto add comma after last character so it will be:

10202, 20192, 29192

Answer (score 1):

To handle the clipboards events, you can use `onPaste` (onCopy onCut onPaste available) https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#clipboard-events

To add a comma there are some ways to do it. A simple one could be to use a regex to find a whitespace and replace it by a whitespace and a comma.

You could also store the values as an array and loop the array and print the value and a comma, it depends on your needs

```js
handlePaste=(e)=>{
  this.setState({
    something: e.target.value.replace(/ /g, ', ')
  })
}

<input value={this.state.something} onPaste={this.handlePaste}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want, but this one solves your above-mentioned problem.

```
function paste(e) {
  return e.clipboardData.getData('text').split(' ').join();
}
```